# Not able to efficiently split two list having multiple spaces and commas using regex python

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I have 2 lists shown below which I am trying to split, however the regex expression used in the code is not efficiently splitting the list.

Input List:

```
Newlist1 = [['66021      4668873364_166638418    3,9202-DC,669251               GEORGIA                 KS 16.0   55    7     0     1     11/03/22 00:00  11/04/22 23:58  11/03/22 00:01   11/18/22 23:59 11/03/22 09:21  11/03/22 09:21  00:00           00:00           1     0'],
 ['18202      4819576505_166636826    4,25340414-VNDR,20536331       BRIDGE TOWNSHIP           PA 0.0    128   219   0     1     11/03/22 00:00  11/03/22 23:58  11/03/22 00:01   11/14/22 23:59 11/03/22 07:30  11/03/22 07:30  00:00           00:00           1     0                                   ']]
```

Below is the code which I am using to split the list

```
def listToString(s):
   
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ""
   
    # return string 
    return (str1.join(s))

       
       
#Driver code

output_list = []
for i in NewList1:
    a= listToString(i)
    output_list.append(re.split("\s{2,}", a))
final = [x for x in output_list if x]
```

Output List:

```
['66021',
  '4668873364_166638418',
  '3,9202-DC,669251',
  'GEORGIA',
  'KS',
  '16.0',
  '55',
  '7',
  '0',
  '1',
  '11/03/22',
  '00:00',
  '11/04/22',
  '23:58',
  '11/03/22',
  '00:01',
  '11/18/22',
  '23:59',
  '11/03/22',
  '09:21',
  '11/03/22',
  '09:21',
  '00:00',
  '00:00',
  '1',
  '0'],
 ['18202',
  '4819576505_166636826',
  '4,25340414-VNDR,20536331',
  'BRIDGE',
  'TOWNSHIP',
  'PA',
  '0.0',
  '128',
  '219',
  '0',
  '1',
  '11/03/22',
  '00:00',
  '11/03/22',
  '23:58',
  '11/03/22',
  '00:01',
  '11/14/22',
  '23:59',
  '11/03/22',
  '07:30',
  '11/03/22',
  '07:30',
  '00:00',
  '00:00',
  '1',
  '0']
```

Expected Output :

```
 ['66021',
  '4668873364_166638418',
  '3,9202-DC,669251',
  'GEORGIA',
  'KS',
  '16.0',
  '55',
  '7',
  '0',
  '1',
  '11/03/22 00:00',
  '11/04/22 23:58',
  '11/03/22 00:01',
  '11/18/22 23:59',
  '11/03/22 09:21',
  '11/03/22 09:21',
  '00:00',
  '00:00',
  '1',
  '0'],
 ['18202',
  '4819576505_166636826',
  '4,25340414-VNDR,20536331',
  'BRIDGE TOWNSHIP',
  'PA',
  '0.0',
  '128',
  '219',
  '0',
  '1',
  '11/03/22 00:00',
  '11/03/22 23:58',
  '11/03/22 00:01',
  '11/14/22 23:59',
  '11/03/22 07:30',
  '11/03/22 07:30',
  '00:00',
  '00:00',
  '1',
  '0']
```

Comment: So your problem is that date and time get split although they only have one space in between? It works as expected for me, but you may try specifying the pattern as a raw string (`r"\s{2,}"`)

Comment: Yes I tried it but doesn't work efficiently now as well

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
import re


Newlist1 = [['66021      4668873364_166638418    3,9202-DC,669251               GEORGIA                 KS 16.0   55    7     0     1     11/03/22 00:00  11/04/22 23:58  11/03/22 00:01   11/18/22 23:59 11/03/22 09:21  11/03/22 09:21  00:00           00:00           1     0'],
 ['18202      4819576505_166636826    4,25340414-VNDR,20536331       BRIDGE TOWNSHIP           PA 0.0    128   219   0     1     11/03/22 00:00  11/03/22 23:58  11/03/22 00:01   11/14/22 23:59 11/03/22 07:30  11/03/22 07:30  00:00           00:00           1     0                                   ']]

pattern = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

for sublist in Newlist1:
    list_str = ''.join(sublist)
    print(re.split(pattern, list_str))
```

The above should print

```
['66021', '4668873364_166638418', '3,9202-DC,669251', 'GEORGIA', 'KS 16.0', '55', '7', '0', '1', '11/03/22 00:00', '11/04/22 23:58', '11/03/22 00:01', '11/18/22 23:59 11/03/22 09:21', '11/03/22 09:21', '00:00', '00:00', '1', '0']
['18202', '4819576505_166636826', '4,25340414-VNDR,20536331', 'BRIDGE TOWNSHIP', 'PA 0.0', '128', '219', '0', '1', '11/03/22 00:00', '11/03/22 23:58', '11/03/22 00:01', '11/14/22 23:59 11/03/22 07:30', '11/03/22 07:30', '00:00', '00:00', '1', '0', '']
```

Note that the second printed list *does* have an empty string `''` at the end of it due to the trailing spaces after the final `0`, but removing any empty strings after the fact should be fairly trivial by doing this instead:

```
for sublist in Newlist1:
    list_str = ''.join(sublist)
    result = re.split(pattern, list_str)
    if not result[-1]:
        result.pop()  # remove the empty string
    print(result)
```